# How do I change the image inside an HTML5 form-validation message?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, webkit, validation

Using [this article](http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/Styling%20Form%20Controls#), I'm changing the styling of some of my HTML5 form-validation pop-ups.  However, my error pop-ups still have the default, orange exclamation point in the error, in addition to the new red X I've added.  How do I get rid of the orange exclamation point (see image below).  So far, I'm only testing in Chrome.

[image: sample error message]

Here is the CSS that I'm using from that article:

```
::-webkit-validation-bubble-message 
{
    color: #eee;
    background: #000;
    border-color: #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px rgba(100,100,100,0.5);
}

::-webkit-validation-bubble-message:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 4px;
    background: url(/myPath/myImage.png)
}

::-webkit-validation-bubble-arrow {
    background: #000;
    border-color: #444;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Please show the code you are using.

Comment: Not sure how to fix this. But, if anyone wants to try see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/adamzr/bugjM/ Just hit submit without filling in the form

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
input::-webkit-validation-bubble-icon {
display: none;
}
```

or, of course:

```
input::-webkit-validation-bubble-icon {
background: url(http://google.com/favicon.ico);
}
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/xhqhV/

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, where might I find documentation that mentions this webkit-validation-bubble-icon?  I could only find info on webkit-validation-message and webkit-validation-message-arrow.

Comment: Here is an important update regarding this answer.
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=293209
In short -- Chrome has stopped supporting this feature.